# How do i read a byte bit by bit with little endianness

Tags: binary, elixir

I'm trying to read a byte bit by bit, but I found the order of the bits to be reversed. I was suggested to me that I was probably reading them wrong (with big endianess), when I should read using little endianess.

The sequence is `1101 0110`.

If I simply pattern match each bit out I get the order mentioned, but the desired order is `0110 1101`.

I tried to add the pattern match out with `little-size(1)` like so

```
<<
  test1::little-size(1),
  test2::little-size(1),
  test3::little-size(1),
  test4::little-size(1),
  test5::little-size(1),
  test6::little-size(1),
  test7::little-size(1),
  test8::little-size(1),
>> = byte
```

But I still get the same bit order, do I need to make a function that reverses them? Or is it baked into Elixir, and I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: So you want to reverse every 4 bits? or is there a typo in the desired order? Endianness refers to the order of complete bytes in a large binary, not bits (or 4 bits) inside a byte.

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, i want to switch the two nibble of each byte. This might put some light on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254886/why-is-bit-buffer-and-buffer-giving-me-different-output "Each of those groups is simply reversed. That's because the human-readable representation is big-endian, and when you read the bit at index 0 that's the rightmost. So if you are reading them bit-by-bit from your stream, you read each byte from the right to the left."

Comment: Endianess is on the level of bytes. A binary byte 01101101 has powers of 2 in the sequence 76543210. So there already is a reversal. In general bit[0] would be sent first: "little endian". **For swapping nibbles the order is irrelevant.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the actual question in the comment:

> I want to switch the two nibble of each byte.

```
iex(1)> binary = <<0b11010110, 0b11010110>>
<<214, 214>>
iex(2)> for << <<a::4, b::4>> <- binary >>, into: <<>>, do: <<b::4, a::4>>
"mm"
iex(3)> <<0b01101101, 0b01101101>>
"mm"
```

We use binary comprehension here to extract two nibbles of the binary at a time and we switch their order and insert it into a new binary.